# How can we calculate $\ln(x) - 1$ at $x \approx e$ using standard double precision arithmetic?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, machine-precision

This question is inspired by the fact that decent mathematical libraries in programming languages compute sine of double precision approximation of $\pi$ correctly to the last bit (example is in Julia):

```
> sin(Float64(π))
1.2246467991473532e-16
```

As a fun fact, it can be used to [extract $\pi$ to quadruple precision](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/) using double precision sine function.

I was wondering, can we easily implement function $\ln(x) - 1$ that would yield correct values for $x \approx e$? **By "easily" I mean without explicitly specifying $e$ to quadruple precision, preferably by just cleverly using available functions from standard double precision math libraries.**

Straightforwardly calculating $\ln(x) - 1$ of double precision approximation of $e$ yields $0.0$:

```
> log(Float64(ℯ)) - 1
0.0
```

while the actual value is

```
> log(BigFloat(Float64(ℯ))) - 1
-5.318237706605891370519835446436883266985903310522696816605415323809030383416923e-17
```

---

**Clarification** I would like to clarify that the idea is not to explicitly use calculations beyond double machine precision. The trick is not to have a series expansion of the function near $x \approx e$ and expand it in terms of $x - e$, the hard part is computing $x - e$ within the double precision arithmetic if $x$ is already approximately $e$ to double precision.

For comparison, if $x = 3.141592653589793$ (actually, its binary approximation, that's important) then we can compute $x - \pi$ as $x - \pi \approx - \sin x$ and standard math library function will give us the correct result, all $\sim 17$ digits. I wondered, can we get the same with $e$ without explicitly going beyond double precision, computing $\ln(x) - 1$ is an equivalent task. Answers of `emacs drives me nuts` and `Somos` do explictly use beyond double precision calculation of $x - e$.

Comment: Are you aware of the closely related $\ln(1+x)$ function? It is commonly included in various math libraries (e.g. C and C++ standard: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log1p) and computes the value with full precision even for $x\approx 0$ (in which case $1+x=1$ in finite precision).

Comment: I don't think the "actual value" is correct. It should be $0$, as $\log(e)-1=0$. If you mean that this is the "actual value" of the closest IEEE-754 number to $e$ then it's just a random number that is going to be of the order of $2^{-53}$.

Comment: @PC1 this is not a random number, this is a well defined unique number, in decimal $\approx -5.3182377066 \cdot 10^{-17}$, though indeed as expected of the order of $2^{-53}$. Just like sine of the closest IEEE-754 number to $\pi$ is a well defined unique number of the order of $2^{-53}$ and standard sine implementations do correctly compute all of its double precision digits .

Comment: Random is not the correct term. However, this number is irrelevant. It’s just an IEEE-754 number that is close to 0. Another algorithm could provide you with a different  number, also close to 0.

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is expanding the Mercator series of $\ln$. Let $x\approx e$, say $x = e+\Delta x$ with $|\Delta x|\ll 1$:

$$\begin{align}
\ln x - 1 = \ln\left(1+\frac{\Delta x}e\right) 
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{\Delta x^n}{ne^n} \\
&= \frac{\Delta x}{e} - \frac{\Delta x^2}{2e^2} +\frac{\Delta x^3}{3e^3} \mp\cdots
\end{align}$$ $\def\artanh{\operatorname{artanh}}$

You might get faster convergence using $\artanh$:

$$\begin{align}
\ln x - 1 &= 2\artanh\frac{\Delta x}{2e+\Delta x} \\
&= 2\xi + \frac23\xi^3+\frac25\xi^5+\frac27\xi^7+\cdots \\
&= 2\xi \left(1 + \xi^2\left(\frac13 + \xi^2\left(\frac15+\xi^2\left(\frac17 + \cdots \right)\right)\right)\right)\tag 2\\
\end{align}$$
with $\xi=\Delta x/(2e+\Delta x)$. As indicated by the last line, evaluation is performed using the Horner scheme.  Start with the highest power $n$ of $\xi$ such that
$$n > 1+\frac{53\ln 2}{1+\ln 2 - \ln \Delta x}$$

For example, if $\Delta x = 10^{-8}$, then $n> 2.82$.  The next-greater odd number is $n=3$ so that 2 terms of  $(2)$ are enough to achieve IEEE-754 double precision.

Comment: Concerning the "tweaking" of the power series for $\ln (1+t)$ when $t$ is close to $0$, let $u=t/(2+t)$. Then $\ln (1+t)=\ln (1+u)-\ln (1-u)=2u(1+u^2/3+u^4/5+...).$

Comment: Is "Mercator series" an Autocorrect?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series

Comment: So how are we going to compute $\Delta x$? For example, in the extreme case $x$ being $e$ to double precision.

Comment: It's $x=e+\Delta x$, thus $\Delta x = x-e$. $e$ as binary float is `0x1.5bf0a8b145769p+1`, for example use GNU-C code `printf ("%a\n", M_E);`.  Then subtract $e$ to get `Δx=1.44564689172925...E-16`.  This is few lines of Python using `Decimal`. It's so small that all you need to compute is $2Δx/(2e+Δx) = Δx/e$ if you use IEEE-754 double.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be easier than you think. Use the
[PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) code

```
? bp=51; N=2^bp; e=exp(1); x=round(e*N)/N; print(y=x/e-1);
-5.3182377066058912291017433304155628559E-17
```

which seems to match your expected result.

Use the fact that if $\,x\approx e,\,$ then $\,y:=x/e\!-\!1\approx 0\,$
which implies that
$$\log(x)\!-\!1 = \log(x/e) = \log(1\!+\!y) = y
 \!+\! O(y^2) \approx y = x/e\!-\!1.$$

**NOTE** the fact that if the bit precision
$51$ is replaced by some other integer close to it,
then the result will be different although it will
still be of the same order of magnitude.

**NOTE** the Wikipedia article
[double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)
states

> Significant precision: 53 bits (52 explictly stored)

The $51$ bits which the PARI/GP computation uses is less than $53$ bits
and therefore it does **not** exceed double precision.

**NOTE** the Mathematica code

```
Sin[Pi // N] // InputForm
(* 1.2246467991473532*^-16 *)
```

matches the Julia result and I can get the same result with Python using
`numpy`, however, so far I can't get Mathematica or Python to produce a
similar result for $\,\log(e)-1.$

Comment: I ran your PARI/GP code and `e` is correct up to 38 digits, far beyond double precision (~17 digits). I looked over the internet, the default PARI/GP precision is around 38 digits on 64 bits machines. It is also indicative that to get Float64 approximation of $e$ you have to specifically round your `e`.

Comment: @Yrogirg Yes, I used the default 38 digits, but I specifically used `x=round(e*N)/N` to round $e$ as you noticed. The principle remains that $y=x/e-1$ is the result you want. I used PARI/GP as a means to that end.

Comment: it works only because PARI/GP by default computes with higher than double precision, for that matter you can just directly compute `log(x) - 1` in PARI/GP, no analysis or tricks required.

Comment: `bp=51; N=2^bp; x=round(e*N)/N; print(log(x)-1);` would be a more concise code in this situation

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$\log(x)-1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac {(x-e)^n}{n\,e^n}$$ the best Padé approximants will be $[p+1,p]$.

For example
$$\color{blue}{P_2=t \,\frac {30+21t+t^2 }{30+36t+9t^2 } }\qquad \text{with} \qquad t=\frac {x-e}e$$ whose error is $\frac {t^6}{600}$.

For $x \in \left\{\frac{95 e}{100},\frac{105 e}{100}\right\}$, the maximum absolute error is $3.0\times 10^{-11}$.

For $x \in \left\{\frac{99 e}{100},\frac{101 e}{100}\right\}$, the maximum absolute error is $1.8\times 10^{-15}$.

The next one seems to be very good

$$\color{blue}{P_3=\frac t {12} \,\,\frac{420+510 t+140 t^2+3 t^3 } {35+60 t+30 t^2+4 t^3}}\qquad \text{with} \qquad t=\frac {x-e}e$$
whose error is $\frac {t^8}{9800}$

For $x \in \left\{\frac{95 e}{100},\frac{105 e}{100}\right\}$, the maximum absolute error is $4.8\times 10^{-15}$.

For $x \in \left\{\frac{99 e}{100},\frac{101 e}{100}\right\}$, the maximum absolute error is $6.4\times 10^{-17}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it somewhat misses the point. Any standard library can compute `log(x) - 1` at `x = Float64(e)` to an absolute error of the order of `1e-17`. The question was how to get to the error of `1e-34` without explicitly going beyond the double precision. In general your method relies on the ability to compute $x - e$ accurately, which is not a given. I admit, this is not a super practical question, it is more akin to somewhat recreational problems of computing with an access just to a basic calculator or much more distantly to constructions with a compass and a ruler.

Answer (score 1):

I see no other way but to explicitly use in the algorithm the difference between $e$ and its Float64 trunction, $de = \mathrm{Float64}(e) - e \approx -1.4456468917292502 \cdot 10^{-16}$. Then we just use the identity

$$
\ln(x) - 1 = \operatorname{ln1p}((x - e) / e)
$$

where $\operatorname{ln1p} = \ln(1+x)$ is a standard library function. In Julia:

```
function log1m(x)
  de = -1.4456468917292502e-16
  dx = x - ℯ
  return log1p((dx+de) / ℯ)
end

> log1m(ℯ)
-5.318237706605892e-17
```

This should compute $\ln(x)-1$ over the entire domain to full double precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do a Padé approximant. For example, using Mathematica:

`PadeApproximant[Log[x] - 1, {x, E, 2}] // Simplify`

gives
$$f(x)\approx\frac{3(x^2-e^2)}{x^2+4ex+e^2}$$

This is very fast to compute (only simple operations) and reasonably close to the real value but will be off by some amount, it all depends on which precision you need. You can add more terms if needed (I used only quadratic approximant).

Comment: For the third degree: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=PadeApproximant%5BLog%5Bx%5D-1%2C%7Bx%2CE%2C3%7D%5D%2F%2FSimplify